# Paste the result of the tee command

Tags: bash

This is only hypothetical question - not solving any real problem - only learning bash.

With the `tee` command is possible split the output to more different streams, like:

```
command1 | tee >(commandA1 | commandA2 >file1) >(commandB1 | commandB2 >file2) >file0
```

so graphically is done the next

```
                  ---commandA1---commandA2--> file1
                 /
command1---tee-------> file0
                 \
                  ---commandB1---commandB2--> file2
```

Now, with the `paste` command can e.g.

```
paste file1 file2 | command3
```

but again i can redirect to the paste output from a different programs, like:

```
paste <(ls) <(ls) | command3
```

The question is: is possible somewhat join the two streams into one, something like

```
                  ---commandA1---commandA2---
                 /                           \
command1---tee-------> file0                  --- paste---command3
                 \                           /
                  ---commandB1---commandB2---
```

Ps: mean without intermediate files...

Comment: Not without an intermediate file or named pipe.  See `mkfifo`

Comment: This is a sort of questions what i love to see - somewhat, what is not trivial. Unfotunately, i don't know bash enough deeply to show how to achieve this with "named pipes" as @Nirk suggested... +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how to do it with named pipes:

```
trap "rm -f /tmp/file1 /tmp/file2; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15
mkfifo /tmp/file1
mkfifo /tmp/file2
command1 | tee >(commandA1 | commandA2 >/tmp/file1) >(commandB1 | commandB2 >/tmp/file2) >file0
paste /tmp/file1 /tmp/file2 | command3
rm -f /tmp/file1 /tmp/file2
trap 0
```

Working example:

```
$ cd -- "$(mktemp -d)" 
$ trap "rm -f pipe1 pipe2; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15
$ mkfifo pipe1 pipe2
$ printf '%s\n' 'line 1' 'line 2' 'line 3' 'line 4' | tee \
>(sed 's/line /l/' | head -n 2 > pipe1) \
>(sed 's/line /Line #/' | tail -n 2 > pipe2) \
> original.txt
$ paste pipe1 pipe2 | sed 's/\t/ --- /'
l1 --- Line #3
l2 --- Line #4
$ rm pipe1 pipe2
$ trap 0
```

Comment: I didn't write it, @JonathanLeffler added that (before you added the working example).

Comment: @l0b0: `exit 1` in the trap to indicate that the process failed; `exit 0` would give the misleading impression that the process succeeded.  And not adding an `exit` would mean 'exit with the status of the last command, which would be `rm -f`, which would succeed, so the exit status would be 0.  The `trap` makes sure that the temporary FIFOs are removed when the shell is able to remove them.  If you kill the process with `kill -9`, there's nothing it can do to clean up.  But if you use HUP, INT, QUIT, PIPE or TERM (1, 2, 3, 13, 15), then the shell will clean up behind itself before exiting.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler What's confusing is that you include `0` in the list of signals that you trap, which means it will run during normal exit and turn it into a failing exit. But that actually won't happen because you disable the trap on exit with `trap 0` at the end, so there's no point of this in the original trap command.

Comment: The trap on 0 isn't material in the code as written; there isn't an exit between when the trap is set and when it is cancelled.  However, it is future proofing the code.  If someone added something in between that did an exit, then the `trap "rm ..." 0` ensures that the cleanup occurs even though they didn't notice.  It is a simple case of defensive programming.  I just remember and use the numbers '0 1 2 3 13 15' automatically, and have done for decades (aeons in Internet time).  (If you really don't like what I added, you can always remove it; that's your choice.)

Comment: @l0b0 In the `trap` command, signal 0 is a special case -- it's used to catch normal exiting of the script, receipt of signal 0 (precisely because of the point you make). Read the `bash` man page.

Comment: TIL: "If a sigspec is EXIT (0) the command arg is executed on exit from the shell." Okidok :)